# Getting an error when trying to do a plot. How do I get finite xlim?

Tags: r, plot

I am very new to R and I am getting an error that I cannot find the answer to from the resources online. Hope you can help!

Here is the error I get when trying to do a simple plot:

```
> plot(PSU.mean ~ Date, data = CTD_mean)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I had previously summarized my data to give me means and sd using dplyr.

```
CTD_mean <- CTD %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(PSU.mean = mean(PSU), PSU.sd = sd(PSU), n = n())
```

Which gave me a tibble as follows (only showing 4 rows out of 135):

```
 Date          PSU.mean PSU.sd     n
   <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1 06-06-2019     27.4  0.262   164
 2 06-07-2019     27.8  0.223   288
 3 06-08-2019     27.8  0.244   288
 4 06-09-2019     27.8  0.233   288
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error. I get the same error even after I turn my data into an 'as.data.frame'.  From previous posts I have also seen people trying to turn the x and y into vectors or 'as.numeric' but none of that has worked.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use your same code with `Date` as `Date` class

Comment: @Raquel can you share more info on your data? Perhaps calling summary() and str() on the date vector.  The info you shared indicates Date is stored as a character vector, which would make it plot as a categorical variable. Does it plot with ggplot? Do you get errors if you transform it to date? See post below?

Comment: Thanks! The as.Date worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the error came from the Date format.
here, what I did:

```r
df = data.frame(Date = c("06-06-2019","06-07-2019","06-08-2019","06-09-2019"),
                PSU.Mean = c(27.4,27.8,27.8,27.8),
                PSU.sd = c(0.262,0.223,0.244,0.233))
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = PSU.Mean)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: In base graphics both of these work even with Date as a character vector: 
plot(PSU.Mean ~ Date, data = df) 
plot(df$Date, df$PSU.Mean)

Comment: @BrianFisher, so it does not explain the error observed by the OP

Comment: I could not reproduce the error mentioned by the OP, so I suspect it had something to do with something in his data structure not included in the post